# Magento 2 : Use plugin / interceptor on abstract class

Tags: magento2, plugin, interceptor

I am trying to create a plugin that fires after `\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Shipment\AbstractShipment\PrintAction::execute`.
So I have my plugin setup in `di.xml` and an `afterExecute()` method, but it doesn't seem to get fired.
Now I know there are [some limitations for plugins](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html), but I can't read anything about abstract classes.
Can plugins / interceptors be used on abstract classes?

Answer (score 5):

Just to answer the real question here: Yes, it is indeed possible to define plugins / interceptors on abstract classes. Doing this works similar to other plugin definitions: An `Interceptor` class will be generated for each subclass of the abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure about this, but I think the plugins work for classes that get instantiated.
The object manager instantiates the `my\class\Interceptor` instead of `my\class` when there are plugins for that class.
Since the abstract classes never get instantiated you won't have an `\Interceptor` class generated that should call the plugins.
But...
I assume there is a class that extends `\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Shipment\AbstractShipment\PrintAction` and that one is actually instantiated and used.
You can try to create the plugin for that class.
Even if that class does not contain the `execute` method, it is still available (via parent class) so this means you should be able to add a plugin to it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I moved my intercepter one level 'lower' but it's not yet getting picked up. It picks my plugin, but as soon as `magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php::146` is executed (which is the call to the original method `$result = parent::$method(...array_values($arguments));`), the headers already get sent and the PDF is sent. Effectively ignoring my `LISTENER_AFTER`.

Comment: maybe you should try an `around` plugin and call the original method inside your plugin.

Comment: Already tried `around`. Before the `callable` the code gets executed, but as soon as I place it after the `callable` it doesn't work. I'm trying to fetch the result of the fileFactory. Could it be that it outputs the header and exits the script? Since I can't find I way to execute code after the PDF generating, I'm now executing it on `before` (which works) but it feels wrong since I only want to execute the code if I'm sure the PDF generation works.

Comment: Got it! Turns out that `Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory::create()` is checking if `$content !== null` and if it's not it indeed starts sending headers and (as I suggested) is doing an `exit(0)`, practically making it impossible for plugins to hook into `after` for this method. I think I'm going to report this as an issue...

Comment: Filed: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7356